# Loosing an XML file when using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

**Sometimes**, when I save to XML, I end up with a completely empty XML file.

I can't reproduce the issue on demand yet. It is just occasional. Are there steps that one can take to assist the user in this regard?

At the moment I do this:

```
public bool SavePublisherData()
{
    bool bSaved = false;

    try
    {
        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(_PublisherData.GetType());
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(_strPathXML))
        {
            _PublisherData.BuildPublisherListFromDictionary();
            x.Serialize(writer, _PublisherData);

            bSaved = true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    return bSaved;
}
```

The reason I have not put anything in the catch block is because this code is part of a C# DLL and I am calling it from an MFC project. I have read that you can't (or shouldn't) pass exceptions through from one environment to another. Thus, when an exception happens in my DLL I don't really know how I can sensibly feed that information to the user so they can see it. That is a side issue.

But this is how I save it. So, what steps can one take to try and prevent complete data loss?

Thank you.

### Update

I have looked at the [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/886385/memory-usage-is-high-when-you-create-several-xmlserializer-objects-in-asp.net) that the link in the comments refers to and it states:

> Use the following XmlSerializer class constructors. These class constructors cache the assemblies.

This is also re-stated in the [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2006/02/15/net-memory-leak-xmlserializing-your-way-to-a-memory-leak/) itself indicated in the comments:

> What is the solution?
>
> The default constructors XmlSerializer(type) and XmlSerializer(type, defaultNameSpace) caches the dynamic assembly so if you use those constructors only one copy of the dynamic assembly needs to be created.
>
> Seems pretty smart… why not do this in all constructors? Hmm… interesting idea, wonder why they didn’t think of that one:) Ok, the other constructors are used for special cases, and the assumption would be that you wouldn’t create a ton of the same XmlSerializers using those special cases, which would mean that we would cache a lot of items we later didn’t need and use up a lot of extra space. Sometimes you have to do what is good for the majority of the people.
>
> So what do you do if you need to use one of the other constructors? My suggestion would be to cache the XmlSerializer if you need to use it often. Then it would only be created once.

My code uses one of these default constructors as you can see:

```
XmlSerializer(_PublisherData.GetType());
```

So I don't think I need to worry about this `XmlSerializerFactory` in this instance.

Comment: Is there a chance that SavePublisherData is being called by multiple threads over the same file?

Comment: @Gusman I would say no to that question. I am running one instance of my application, and the interface is within a wrapper that is available via the app class. And I call the method once. So I can't see that it is being called multiple times.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle What exactly are you serializing? Does it vary? Have you tried locking the XML file?

Comment: @PaulZahra How do you lock the XML file?

Comment: Are there multiple users running this or just one at a time? Try something like a singleton. Have a look at http://www.theroks.com/using-the-xmlserializer-in-multithreaded-applications/

Comment: @PaulZahra At the moment this file is local to the user.

Comment: As the link I gave explains, if it can be run in a multi-threaded manor, issues can ensue... try locking it, again as explained in the link, make sure you use XmlSerializerFactory.

Comment: @PaulZahra Thanks. Out of interest, why does the Microsoft link say it is retired content? It does not offer updated article.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I believe it's just MS doing a general clean up... Singleton pattern is still relevant and will be for a long time.

Comment: @PaulZahra Sure! But, since my MFC application is using a mutex to limit to one instance, I wonder if I need these changes on the DLL side. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I guess that depends on how you are using XmlSerializer within your single application instance... also the additional benefit of using the XmlSerializerFactory in a singleton is to prevent the (by design) memory leak of XmlSerializer http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/02/15/532804.aspx and of course make sure you handle the mutex (and any exceptions) properly... sometimes it's just easier/better to loop through all process full paths to ensure another instance isn't running... and then there's the race condition to consider... euch.